# Why does my website work in the stack overflow preview but not on replit?

Tags: javascript, html, css, null, typeerror

When I try to hide a div on my website by using "document.getElementById('number-panel').style.display = 'none'," on replit, it says that it "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')." But I put this same code into stack overflow's preview, and it works perfectly? How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```js
/*$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".number-panel").hide();
  $(#generate).click(function() {
    $(".number-panel").fadeIn();
  });
});*/

document.getElementById("number-panel").style.display = "none";

function generateNumber() {
  let min = document.getElementById("lowest").value;
  let max = document.getElementById("highest").value;
  let numberDisplay = document.getElementById("random-number");

  if (min != undefined && max != undefined) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + (min + 1));
    numberDisplay.innerHTML = randomNumber;
    document.getElementById("number-panel").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
    html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background-image: radial-gradient(#b8c6ff, #a8baff);
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: Figtree;
      src: url(Figtree-VariableFont_wght.ttf);
    }

    #title {
      transition: font-size 1s;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Figtree;
      color: white;
      padding-top: 22px;
      font-size: 37px;
    }

    /*#title:hover {
      font-size: 40px;
      cursor: default;
    } */

    #generate {
      transition: height 0.5s, width 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
      background-color: #ffd1d9;
      height: 55px;
      width: 111px;
      font-family: Figtree;
      color: #9e6eaf;
      font-size: 22px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #e67a7a;
      position: absolute;
      top: 22%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      margin-top: 22px;
      margin-left: -44px;
    }

    #generate:hover {
      height: 59px;
      width: 115px;
      font-size: 23px;
    }

    input[type=number] {
      transition: background-color 0.5s;
      margin-bottom: 11px;
      position: relative;
      left: 44%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      height: 33px;
      width: 77px;
      font-size: 22px;
      border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      background-color: white;
    }

    input[type=number]:hover {
      background-color: #ededed;
    }

    #to {
      transition: transform 0.5s;
      position: absolute;
      top: 12%;
      left: 48%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      color: white;
      font-family: Figtree;
      font-size: 22px;
    }

    #pick {
      color: white;
      font-family: Figtree;
      font-size: 22px;
      transition: transform 0.5s;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      left: 33%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .number-panel {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
      height: 444px;
      width: 333px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 33%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    #number-panel {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
      height: 444px;
      width: 333px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 33%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    #generate-again {
      transition: background-color 1s;
      margin-top: 55%;
      margin-left: 33%;
      height: 44px;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-family: Figtree;
      background-color: #ffc7c7;
      color: #454545;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #2b2b2b;
    }
    #random-number{
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 44px;
      color: white;
      font-family: Figtree;
    }
    #random-is {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Figtree;
      color: white;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!--
  This script places a badge on your repl's full-browser view back to your repl's cover
  page. Try various colors for the theme: dark, light, red, orange, yellow, lime, green,
  teal, blue, blurple, magenta, pink!
  -->
  <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge-v2.js" theme="dark" position="bottom-right"></script>
  <h1 id = "title">Random Number Generator!</h1>
  <input type = "number" id = "lowest" />
  <br>
  <input type = "number" id = "highest" />
  <p id = "pick">Pick a random number from</p>
  <p id = "to">to</p>
 <button id = "generate" onclick = "generateNumber()">Generate!</button>
  <div class = "number-panel" id = "number-panel">
    <p id = "random-is">Your random number is</p>
    <p id = "random-number">1</p>
    <button id = "generate-again">Generate Again!</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to be working in the snippet either...

Comment: FWIW, I'm getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" thrown at `jquery-ui.js:10:2`, and the Figtree font doesn't load either.

Comment: Your div number-panel is not yet loaded at the point that JS is run. Reorder your code so that JS comes at the end or wait for the load event before running it.

Comment: A bug to fix soonish: the `value` property of an HTMLInputElement is of type "string", while  the `valueAsNumber` property of an HTMLInputElement of type "number" is of type "number". Use  `valueAsNumber` to prevent `(min+1)` in the code performing string concatenation instead of arithmetic addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code may have worked on your machine if you tested it as a Stack Overflow snippet and also loaded `jquery.js` on which `jqueryui.js` depends.  That's two separate reasons: providing the JavaScript content of `script.js` in the "JavaScript" box of the stack snippet editor, and loading `jQuery.js` in the page.

1. Code entered in the JavaScript box of the snippet editor gets placed at the **bottom** of the `<body>` element after all the HTML has been parsed and elements defined in HTML added to the DOM. The editor seems to get it in the right spot even if you have entered a complete HTML document with head and body sections in the HTML box.

   It doesn't work on a server however, because loading `script.js` is performed at the top of the body section, before any HTML elements have been parsed or placed in the DOM. Hence the `null` values being returned by `getElementById()` calls.
2. I can only guess that you were loading `jquery.js` but removed it from the post (by mistake) at the same time the jQuery code in the JavaScript was commented out - even though `jquery-ui.js` also needs`jquery.js` to run.

There is a quite separate issue with using the string value of an input element of type "number" instead of the numeric value of the string - see my question comment for details.

Comment: I put the script at the bottom of the HTML and it worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that a tag with the `id` of `number-panel` does not exist at the time when it is being searched for via

```
document.getElementById('number-panel').style.display = 'none';
```

So, it the case that the tag is simply not existent yet (or no longer existent) when you try to infer it. You will need to think through how your script needs to operate, the solution is likely to create a load event listener and execute your Javascript inside of that.